# SaaS, multi-tenant architecture with Symfony 4 (one app many databases)?

Tags: doctrine-orm, multi-tenant, symfony4, saas

I've been looking for a multi-tenant architecture solution with **Symfony 4 & Doctrine** for a long time, where we have single App and many databases.
So, i've managed a little with this: [sf4-multi-tenancy](https://github.com/amurzaliev/sf4-multi-tenancy).
But i'm not sure if is good solution.

If anybody is interested of such task, please write your code review or maybe advice something. And my question is: where i can find open source projects on Symfony with such architecture? I want to be sure, that everything i've done will work well.

I hope, it will be useful for somebody. And, sorry for my english :)